# Apache Cordova InAppBrowser shows keyboard and hides it immediatly

Tags: android, apache, cordova, keyboard, inappbrowser

I've got an Cordova PhoneGap application, that is loading the Google Authorisation page. If I click on an input field, the keyboard shows up for about 300ms and then closes instantly. What have I done wrong? I open the InAppBrowser in the following way:

```
this.popup = window.open( c_encode(self.providerURLs[provider]), "_blank",
```

"EnableViewPortScale=yes,location=yes" );

Best Regards

Daniel Gruber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the executeScript functionality of the inappbrowser plugin? Maybe even an interval?

This would close the keyboard on older devices, see this bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5449